# Trying to implement a loop in Makefile target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

This is my target, where i want to run a loop for each element in the list variable.
The problem is the loop runs but the `test` variable value is passed as empty

```
list = mlflow emr
common=$(someDir)/common
.PHONY:build
build:
    for var in $(list); do \
        cd ${common}; \
        test=$(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AM master | grep ^$(var)/); \
        if [ "$(test)" != "" ]; then \
            echo "condition met"; \
        else \
            echo "It is Not Setup"; \
        fi \
    done
```

Error:

```
bash-5.0# sudo make build n=1
for var in mlflow emr; do \
    cd /mak/epa-toolchain/common; \
    test=; \
    if [ "" != "" ]; then \
        echo "condition met"; \
    else \
        echo "It is Not Setup"; \
    fi \
done
It is Not Setup
It is Not Setup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` is a special character to make: it introduces a make variable reference.  So this:

```
$(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AM master | grep ^$(var)/)
```

is not a shell `$(...)` command, it's a make variable with a very strange name.  Wherever you want the shell to see `$` you have to escape it as `$$`:

```
$$(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AM master | grep ^$$var/)
```

(note you have to change `$(var)` to `$$var` because the former is a reference to a *make* variable `var`, but you are looping in the *shell* which sets the *shell* variable `var`).

Ditto this:

```
    if [ "$(test)" != "" ]; then \
```

has to be:

```
    if [ "$$test" != "" ]; then \
```

because `test` is a *shell* variable you just assigned, not a *make* variable.

Comment: indeed it works, thanks for the clear explanation and prompt rely